# Can I Install SP016 on a Single VM with SQL 2014 and Active Directory to Evaluate

Tags: 2016

Due to resource constraints, I'd like to install SharePoint 2016 Beta 2 on a Single VM that is a Domain Controller (Win2012R2) and SQL 2014 all together.

Can I effectively do this?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, we have done so successfully. There is no additional steps required compared to SP 2013

Comment: Don't forget to mark a question as an answer if it helped you.